# Is there a Microsoft.CSharp in mono (2.10)?

Tags: c#, mono

Does mono have a CSharpCodeProvider implemented that I should be using
instead of Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider?

I am using the class to dynamically compile c# scripts from a compiled
program but mono throws an error under linux:
->Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find
the specified file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use the Mono.CSharp.Evaluator class in the Mono.Sharp.dll assembly

Answer (score -1):

It should work under Mono. If you are using Linux, make sure your DLLs are in your path and make sure you are properly capitalizing it. Linux is case sensitive and it may not find `System.dll` if your code says `system.dll`

Comment: no, make sure the assembly is in your exe's folder, the GAC or in MONO_PATH

Comment: @Ian - That is what I said `"make sure your DLLs are in your path"`